# How do I find an anchor following a specific text

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML block. I want to use jQuery to find the anchor following the text "Text before the second link". The anchor may or may not be the last one as in this example, but it will always be immediately following the text.

```
<div>
  Text before the first link 
  <a href="">First Link</a>
  Text before the second link 
  <a href="">I want to grab this link</a> <!-- I want to grab this anchor -->
</div>
```

Comment: I would also add that `.nextSibling` can/may select the next text node, if it is empty char, so it should be checked against that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
var elem = $();
$("div").contents().each(function(){
  if(this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() == "Text before the second link"){
    elem = elem.add(this.nextElementSibling);
  }
});

elem.css("color","red");
```

use `.contents()` to receive the contents inside of that `div`. contents includes element node,comment nodes and text nodes. So the node type of a text node is `3`. Check the individual content based on node type along with the text value and add it to the empty jquery object.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/LvbusLjc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contents()` to find the textnode with the given text content. From there you can use `nextSibling` to get the `a`. Try this:

```
var node = $('div').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() == 'Text before the second link';
}).get(0);
var $a = $(node.nextSibling);
// do something with $a here...
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/k58zxpn0/)

Comment: Its good to feel when an expert thinks in the way that I think. :)